# Fill null values in a column using percent change from a second column while grouping by a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
grp    val    run
a      5      10
b      10     1
a      NaN    8
a      NaN    4
b      NaN    5
b      NaN    4
a      10     6
a      NaN    6
```

I want to fill in the gaps in the `val` column by applying the same percent change as was calculated. However I also need to group using the `grp` column. I should end up with something like this:

```
grp    val    run
a      5      10
b      10     1
a      4      8
a      2      4
b      50     5
b      40     4
a      10     6
a      10     6
```

I only want to replace values that are null. Notice the 10 in row seven "resets" the forward fill.

Without having to group, I could simply get the percent change in `run` and multiply the previous row's `val` cell by the current row's percent change cell wherever `val` is not null.

I was thinking that I could order the dataframe using `grp`, but then I would still have to worry about the edge case of when `grp` values change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try:

```
# identify the na blocks and group by `grp` and these blocks
na_blocks = df['val'].notna().groupby(df['grp']).cumsum()    
g = df.groupby(['grp', na_blocks])

# "pct change" on run
df['x'] = df['run'] / g['run'].shift(fill_value=1)

# cumprod() for cumulative change
# `ffill` and `transform('first')` behave the same 
# since we are grouping on non-nan following by consecutive nan's
df['val'] = g['val'].ffill() * g['x'].cumprod() / g['run'].transform('first')
```

Output (`x` the extra column that can be dropped):

```
  grp   val  run     x
0   a   5.0   10  10.0
1   b  10.0    1   1.0
2   a   4.0    8   0.8
3   a   2.0    4   0.5
4   b  50.0    5   5.0
5   b  40.0    4   0.8
6   a  10.0    6   6.0
7   a  10.0    6   1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

let us try create new group by key with `cumsum` , then do `groupby` with `transform`

```
s = df.groupby('grp').val.apply(lambda x : x.notna().cumsum())
df['new'] = df.groupby([df.grp,s]).val.ffill().mul(df.run,axis=0).div(df.groupby([df.grp,s]).run.transform('first'))
df
  grp   val  run   new
0   a   5.0   10   5.0
1   b  10.0    1  10.0
2   a   NaN    8   4.0
3   a   NaN    4   2.0
4   b   NaN    5  50.0
5   b   NaN    4  40.0
6   a  10.0    6  10.0
7   a   NaN    6  10.0
```